# Mythologies or folktales regarding dormouse/mouse?

Tags: folklore

I’m trying to create a character based on a powerful and immortal god, but I kind of want a mouse to represent that as it would fit into my story of how the character is portrayed. I was thinking of just doing *Alice in Wonderland*, but she’s very timid and harmless so she isn’t exactly the character in the book.

Answer (score 1):

[The Wedding of the Mouse](http://www.talesofpanchatantra.com/the-wedding-of-the-mouse).

I have linked to an Indian version of it, but there are many variants (not all featuring mice), wherein a quest for what is the most powerful has each being in turn claim that another is more powerful, ending with a mouse being most powerful because it can create holes in the last. (Or a woodcutter because he can chop down a tree.)